# Magento 2 : Sort by Doesn't Work on Catalogsearch Page

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, ajax, search, sort

I have used ajax layered navigation plugin in which i am facing an **issue** like when I search for eg: samsung, it shows all the products of samsung on catalogSearch page.

i.e, **catalogsearch/result/?q=samsung** page.

1. When I change the view i.e, from grid to list view, it doesn't work.
2. When I change the sort by to price or relevance, it doesn't work.

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Have you check concol or magento log files for error.

Comment: no error is displayed